# Keep on dreaming

Tags: classical-latin, english-to-latin-translation

My niece is turning 18 and I want to get her a bracelet with something in Latin engraved. Im looking for something in the lines of "keep on dreaming".

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to the site.

If the text has to go on a bracelet, it must be short. 
Rather than providing a literal translation, I'd go for something that reflects the spirit.
If we interpret "keep on dreaming" as "may you always have dreams", you could write
**Semper somnia tecum sint** (literally: "May dreams be always with you"). 
You can leave out **sint** as that might be implicit.

Comment: The question in my mind is whether _somnium_ and its associated verb have the sense "aspiration", "desire", as well as the primary meaning "inner experience while sleeping". If they do not, they surely don't match the intended meaning.

Answer (score 2):

One option could be *obdura imaginans*, where *[obdura](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/obduro#Latin)* is "endure", and *[imaginans](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/imaginor)* is "imagining". As Colin suggested, the word "dream" (*somnium*) seems not to have the meaning you want in Latin.

Answer (score 1):

The imperfect subjunctive "somniares" giving "might/ may you dream"--a non-specific gentle way of expression.

In the wake of the contribution from Joonas, it may be more appropriate to use the present subjunctive, "somnies" (may you dream). It is shorter and will more readily fit in the limited space.

Comment: I thought that the wish is unreal if you use imperfect instead of present subjunctive. "If only you kept on dreaming!"

Comment: ªJoonas llmavirta: Where does "if only" come from: thougt the idea was to create an unreal/ fantasy/ dream-world? Could use present subjuctive (somnies) may-you-dream; but it is harsh in iussive/ hortative demanding sense eg habeas corpus--a pres. subj. with imperative force: not "you may have a body"; but,  "you HAVE a body!!"

Comment: When a subjunctive/conjunctive is used optatively, the imperfect tense implies unreal, present implies real. So: *Felix sis!* = "May you be happy (and I think you might)!" & *Felix esses!* = "I wish you were happy (but I know you aren't)!" Dreaming can indeed produce a fantasy world, but the act of dreaming is very true. The unreal nature can be emphasized by *utinam* or some such word, but I don't think it has to be. (By the way, to ping a user, use `@` instead of `ª`. The latter doesn't cause the system to ping the user.)